# click button in jruby + celerity

Tags: ruby, jruby, celerity

I'm trying to do some screen scraping, and I've gotten down to this last step. I'm trying to download a file, which is accessed via a button from the following html:

```
<button class="pdf ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">
<span class="icon-32 pdf-32"></span>
<span class="btn-txt"> PDF file </span>
```

I'm used to clicking buttons with the following ruby code:

```
browser.button(:value, "Sign In").click
```

But with this .. there doesn't seem to be any value I can use. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple possibilities. One is that you can do a regular expression match on the value. Try:

```
browser.button(:value, /PDF file/).click
```

But you don't have to use the value, you can use a uniquely identifying attribute. In this case, you may be able to use the class, e.g.

```
browser.button(:class, "pdf").click
```

If the pdf class is not unique, you can add an `:index` to identify which one of the matches to click.